# After save stay in PersonalView.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have for different Users `Home.aspx` and `PersonalView.aspx`, when I am in `PersonalView.aspx` and manage some Tasks, after click on **SAVE** that jumps to `Home.aspx` automatically.

Is there a way to prevent this?

SharePoint online/PersonalView/Custom Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to append source query string parameter in your custom form URL. This way once the form is saved it will redirect user to the source URL from the query string parameter (Even if it is external - Yes external URL works too).

I have this tested with default new/edit forms. I guess it will work for your scenario as well, try and let me know.

> http://sp2013/lists/someList/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://www.google.com

Comment: That redirecting me to `active.aspx` what looks like `Home.aspx` and i can't  find anywhere this **URL** in the code. I am using SharePoint Designer for the Forms. 

Apologies for my mistakes, I am new at Stack Exchange

Comment: Hi, i tried many things but nothing happened.